# Push empty row with input field using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I have one table which have edit, delete and add options. My problem is when I click on add button want to add row with empty input fields. I have write below code for this. What should I do to add empty row with empty input values.

[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/Thw8n/568/)

```
    <div ng-controller="AppKeysCtrl">
<button ng-click="add()">
Add
</button>
<table class="table table-hover mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>App Key</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Level</th>
 http://jsfiddle.net/Thw8n/155/#update           <th>Active</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="entry in appkeys" data-ng-class="{danger:!entry.active}">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td>{{entry.timestamp | date:'mediumDate'}}</td>
        <td>{{entry.appkey}}</td>
        <td>
            <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{entry.name}}</span>
            <input type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-model="entry.name" data-ng-required />
        </td>
        <td>
            <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{entry.level}}</span>
            <select class="form-control" name="entry.level" data-ng-model="entry.level" data-ng-show="editMode">
                <option value="3">3 - Developer Access - [Temporary]</option>
                <option value="2">2 - Standard Tool Access - [Default]</option>
                <option value="1">1 - Administrative Access - [Admin Section Only]</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{entry.active && 'Active' || 'Inactive'}}</span>
            <select class="form-control" name="entry.active" data-ng-model="entry.active" data-ng-show="editMode">
                <option value="true">Active</option>
                <option value="false">Inactive</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" data-ng-hide="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = true; editAppKey(entry)" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
            <button type="submit" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = false" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
            <button type="submit" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = false; cancel($index)" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
        </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
    <pre>newField: {{newField|json}}</pre></br></br>
    <pre>appkeys: {{appkeys|json}}</pre>
</div>

app = angular.module("formDemo", []);

function AppKeysCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
    var tmpDate = new Date();

          $scope.newField = [];
          $scope.editing = false;

     $scope.appkeys = [
         { "appkey" : "0123456789", "name" : "My new app key", "created" : tmpDate },
         { "appkey" : "abcdefghij", "name" : "Someone elses app key", "created" : tmpDate }
     ];

    $scope.editAppKey = function(field) {
        $scope.editing = $scope.appkeys.indexOf(field);
        $scope.newField[$scope.editing] = angular.copy(field);
    }

    $scope.saveField = function(index) {
        //if ($scope.editing !== false) {
            $scope.appkeys[$scope.editing] = $scope.newField;
            //$scope.editing = false;
        //}       
   };

    $scope.cancel = function(index) {
        //if ($scope.editing !== false) {
            $scope.appkeys[index] = $scope.newField[index];
            $scope.editing = false;
        //}       
    };

    $scope.add = function () {
            var entry = {};
            //$scope.goals.push(goal);
            $scope.appkeys.push(entry);
        };
}

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ["formDemo"]);
});
```

I have problem in this that when I click on add empty row is adding which have form fields with ng-hide attribute. I want to add row dynamically with new input boxes for each column. What should I do for this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple. You need to push an object with blank value into your array.

Below is the code:

**Controller**

```
$scope.add = function () {   
      $scope.appkeys.push({appkey : '', name : '', created : '' });
};
```

The above code will only add a row. I have updated your JSFiddle for your desired output.

Please go through with the given link.

http://jsfiddle.net/Thw8n/570/

Comment: Thanks for answer but I want to add <input type="text"> in each column when I click on add button

Comment: Edit button is working fine in my example but when I click on add button i want to add structure like this <td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td>

Comment: why you are not trying ng-bind-html everytime you call a function on add button. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: @vedankitakumbhar, I have updated my answer. I updated the the jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank u so much. I want exactly the same answer. I have implemented this in my code getting error like "Cannot set property '1' of undefined" is any idea about this error.

Comment: Can you mark it right? And the error is because you might forget to => $scope.editMode = []; Do this.

Comment: I have added all your edits but still getting issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to paste the following code:

```
   $scope.add = function () {

           $scope.appkeys.push({appkey : '', name : '', created : '' });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push object with empty properties in your `appkey` array:

```
var tempObject = {
    "appkey":"",
    "name":"",
    "created":""
};
$scope.appkeys.push(tempObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but when I click on add button i want to add structure like this <td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td>